# How to present records in a horizontal row, including images?

Tags: home-page-component, lightning-home-page

This is how I would like to present a number of custom object records:

[image]

So: a horizontal row, with for each record: an thumbnail image or icon, a title, a text and a record. I would like to have this on the home page of an app.

When I look at the available components for a Lightning Home page, nothing comes close. It's only lists, never columns. Even the Accordion component turns out to be a kind of list.

I could always make a custom Lightning Web Component, but it would be nice if I could use an Out of the Box component.